# Gradle - Create custom Groovy library with Java dependencies (apache commons)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, groovy, buildship

I'm trying to create a groovy library (JAR) using java dependencies with no success. I managed to use simple methods, but when my code use third party libraries it won't find the related class.

Gradle version: 5.2

Groovy 1.8.9

Project Structure:

[image]

build.gradle

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Groovy project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Groovy Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/5.2/userguide/tutorial_groovy_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the groovy plugin to add support for Groovy
    id 'groovy'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // Use the latest Groovy version for building this library
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.8'
    compile  group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.2.4'
    compile  group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'

   // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-core
    testCompile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.1-groovy-2.4'

}
```

settings.gradle

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * The settings file is used to specify which projects to include in your build.
 *
 * Detailed information about configuring a multi-project build in Gradle can be found
 * in the user manual at https://docs.gradle.org/5.2/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
 */

rootProject.name = 'com.itau.plugins'
```

MyClassWithDependencies:

```
package com.itau.plugins

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils


class MyClassWithDependencies {

    def copy(source, destination) {
        FileUtils.copyFile(new File(source), new File(destination))
    }

    def copyDir(source, destination) {
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(source), new File(destination))
    }

}
```

The error is pretty clear:

**When i try to import it throws `Groovy:unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`**

And, when i run `gradlew build --no-build-cache` the output is

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s                                                                                                                                                                                  
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
```

and my gradle dependencies are (i guess a picture is the best option here):

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I managed to create a Fat Jar but that's not what i need.

Comment: Not sure why a fat jar isn't what you need? Can you explain?

Comment: Cause that's my requirement (apparently because they will break other dependencies)

Comment: if build was successful, i can't understand when you have an error...

Comment: In Eclipse: right-click your project -> Gradle refresh.

Comment: If gradle dependencies have been loaded you will see a class path container named Project and External Dependencies. You can remove the Groovy Libraries container; it's redundant.